# C- Linked List traversing issue

Tags: c, list, linked-list, deque

Ok so I have the following code:

```
typedef struct node {
char line[3];
struct node* next;
}NODE;

NODE * enq(char b[]);
NODE * deq(NODE *head);
void printQueue (NODE *head);

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char* filename = "expressions.txt";
    char buffer[50];
    int len;

    struct node *head = NULL, *tail, *temp, *temp2;

    if((fp=fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }


    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) !=NULL)
    {
        len=strlen(buffer);
        if(buffer[len-1]=='\n')
            buffer[len-1]='\0';

        if (strcmp("=",buffer) ==0)
        {

            printQueue(head);
        }
        else
        {           
            temp = enq(buffer);

            if(head ==NULL)
                head = temp;
            else
                tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

    }

    NODE * enq(char b[])
    {
        NODE *temp = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        strcpy(temp->line, b);
        temp -> next = NULL;    

        return temp;
    }

    NODE *deq(NODE *head)
    {
        NODE *temp = head->next;

        free(head);
        return temp;
    }

    void printQueue (NODE *head)
   {
        char hold[3];
        int sum = 0, place, sign;
        while(head !=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(hold, head->line);
            if(hold[0] < 58 && hold[0]>47)
            {
                place = atoi(hold);
                if (sign == -1)
                {
                   place = place *sign;
                   sign = 1;
                }
                sum = sum + place;
           }
           else if (strcmp(hold, "-")==0)
           {
              sign = -1;
          }
          printf("%s ", hold);
        head=deq(head);
      }
     printf("= %d\n",sum);

     }
```

This is my input data from the file:

```
71
-
67
-
71
+
9
-
19
=
27
+
8
+
10
-
94
-
64
=
```

The expected output is this:

```
71 - 67 - 71 + 9 - 19 = -77
27 + 8 + 10 - 94 - 64 = -113
```

Output I am getting:

```
71 - 67 - 71 + 9 - 19 = -77
64 = 64
```

It always does the first set of expressions correctly, any expression after that, it skips some of the elements in the linked list, now I THINK I have narrowed it down to the dequeue method, that is not working correctly when I am freeing head.  If I don't free and just test the print output, it prints out every single element in the list which is ok for observations but at the end of the day, I need to free each node as I extract it from the list and I am not sure why it is skipping a whole bunch of nodes.  I printed the list before it is sent to printQueue and it seems fine, but right after dequeueing, the elements start to disappear.  Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you forget to reset the head pointer after you printed the result of an expression and are starting to parse a new expression (hence, a new linked list).

In your main(), try to replace the snippet

```
    if (strcmp("=",buffer) ==0)
    {

        printQueue(head);
    }
```

by

```
    if (strcmp("=",buffer) ==0)
    {

        printQueue(head);
        head = NULL;
    }
```

And you should get the expected output.

Please also beware of the memory leak that would happen if your input file does not end by a '=' (this would not call your printQueue() in which you currently free your list nodes).

Comment: Thanks!  Such a simple issue I overlooked, but it works the way it is supposed to now.  And in my case, the file will always end in an '=' sign so I don't have to worry about that.